# eclipse rcp plugin - removing default title bar of workbench window

Tags: eclipse-rcp, titlebar

I want my rcp plugin without the default title bar and border. I have tried `configuerer.setshellstyle (SWT.No_TRIM)`. But it does not work.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in Eclipse 4 the `setShellStyle` call is being ignored (see Eclipse bug [432501](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=432501)).

You might be able to use the 'styleOveride' value in the LegacyIDE.e4xmi file to set the style (more details [here](http://blog.vogella.com/2014/03/17/using-eclipse-application-model-persisted-state-to-specify-the-swt-stylebits/))

Comment: What about eclipse 3.x?

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK I think it is OK if you are using Eclipse 3.8 or earlier.

Comment: Thank you for clarify. Can i atleast change the colour of titleBar . I have defined a extension point for theme but how to implement it ? I am not using e4